# Perl code ! What does it do (Hash of hashes)?

Tags: perl, hash

I'm currently working on some code written by the previous internship student. I'm not familiar to Perl so I have some problems in understanding what his code actually do. So it looks like:

```
$Hash{Key1}{Key2}++;
```

The original code was:

```
$genotypes_parent2_array{$real_genotype}{$individu_depth}++;
```

I use to see hashes in this form $Hash{Key} in order to get the value but I struggle with this one. Any help out there ? 
Thanks!

Comment: More information on complex structures can be found in [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: A hash is like an array, but rather than being indexed by a number like `0...10` it is indexed by a key which is more like a string. A hash of hashes is like a 2-D array, but instead of two numeric indices, it is indexed by two keys (or strings).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`%Hash` is a hash of hashes.

That codes add `1` to the value of `$Hash{Key1}{Key2}` which is the value of a hash element.

Comment: It appears now more clear to me. I thought the "++ "sign added 1 to the value of the key 1 (or 2). Since they could be strings, I couldn't understant how it was possible. Actually he just initialized a hash (which was previously empty) with two keys in ordrer to add 1 to that null value everytime an particular condition is verified.

Thank you for yout help. :)

Comment: It is called autovivification (see https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/). $Hash is a hash. The value $Hash{Key1} is reference to a newly created hash. The value $Hash{Key1}->{Key2} (the -> is optional) will be the number that will be incremented.

Answer (score 4):

`%genotypes_parent2_array` is a hash (so that's not a very good name for the variable!) Each value in the hash is a hash reference. So effectively you have a hash of hashes.

`$genotypes_parent2_array{$real_genotype}` looks up the key `$real_genotype` in the hash. And that value is (as we said above) a hash reference. If you have a hash reference, then you can look up values in the referenced hash using an arrow. So we can get to a value in the second-level hash using code like this:

```
$genotypes_parent2_array{$real_genotype}->{$individu_depth}
```

However, Perl has a nice piece of syntactic sugar. When you have two pairs of "look-up brackets" next to each other (as we have here) you can omit the arrow. So you can get exactly the same effect with:

```
$genotypes_parent2_array{$real_genotype}{$individu_depth}
```

And that's what we have here. We look up the key `$real_genotype` in the hash `%genotypes_parent2_array`. This gives us a hash reference. We then look up the key `$individu_depth` in the referenced array and that gives us the value in the second-level hash. Your code then increments that value.

The manual page [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) is a good introduction to using references to build complex data structures in Perl. In addition, I find [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) very useful for showing what a complex data structure looks like.